# C# Xml XDocument - Need to convert related duplcate Node Names to be Unique

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

First I am new to xml.  Have read a lot about XmlDocument and XDocument.  Need some help sorting out the following functionality.

I have a reason I need all duplicate (same level, same ancestors / parents to be unique regardless of how far down an xml structure.

in the sample file below... There are two node names at positions 11 & 12 called "entry" that have the same nested parents (ie, result/products or ancestor().count() == 2)  later on in this sample file... there is another sequence of nodes that are named "entry" however their parent nodes are result/forms/required/. (or ancestor().count() == 3)

can someone help me with the recursive code to find matching nodes that's parents match and append an underscore followed by a number as in "entry_1, entry _2. ...  entry_99" and write the xml back out to a file.

To be extra clear each node that is a sibling node with the same name should start at _1 UNLESS the parents match a sibling with an existing appended "_Number".

Thank you for your help, suggestions and ideas !!

- John

Sample File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <result>
  <quote><![CDATA[1776.5]]></quote>
  <account_name><![CDATA[Acme Mountaineers]]></account_name>
  <account_number><![CDATA[CDTEST-07052016]]></account_number>
  <effective_dt><![CDATA[1467676800]]></effective_dt>
  <effective_dt_string><![CDATA[2016-07-05T00:00:00+00:00]]></effective_dt_string>
  <zip><![CDATA[25301]]></zip>
  <street><![CDATA[170 SE 3rd Ave]]></street>
  <city><![CDATA[CHARLESTON]]></city>
  <state><![CDATA[WV]]></state>
  <products>
    <entry><![CDATA[gl]]></entry>
    <entry><![CDATA[auto]]></entry>
  </products>
  <coverage_type><![CDATA[Occurrence]]></coverage_type>
  <product_type><![CDATA[Excess]]></product_type>
  <admitted_status><![CDATA[Non Admitted]]></admitted_status>
  <classifications>
    <entry>
      <location><![CDATA[1]]></location>
      <street><![CDATA[170 SE 3rd Ave]]></street>
      <city><![CDATA[CHARLESTON]]></city>
      <county><![CDATA[KANAWHA]]></county>
      <state><![CDATA[WV]]></state>
      <territory><![CDATA[1]]></territory>
      <zip><![CDATA[25301]]></zip>
      <class_code><![CDATA[91582]]></class_code>
      <class_code_desc><![CDATA[(91582) Contractors - subcontracted work - in connection with building construction, reconstruction,]]></class_code_desc>
      <premium_basis><![CDATA[Total Cost]]></premium_basis>
      <premium_basis_amount><![CDATA[200000]]></premium_basis_amount>
      <authority><![CDATA[A]]></authority>
    </entry>
  </classifications>
  <limit><![CDATA[1,000,000 CSL]]></limit>
  <limit_aggregate><![CDATA[1,000,000 CSL]]></limit_aggregate>
  <aggregate_prod_ops><![CDATA[1,000,000 CSL]]></aggregate_prod_ops>
  <exclude_prod_ops><![CDATA[0]]></exclude_prod_ops>
  <exclude_terrorism><![CDATA[1]]></exclude_terrorism>
  <forms>
    <required>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX DS 01 05 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Declarations]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[HU DS 02 10 15]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Signature Endorsement]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX DS 02 05 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Schedule of Forms and Endorsements]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX DS 03 05 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Schedule of Controlling Underlying Insurance]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[CX 00 01 04 13]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Commercial Excess Liability Form]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX 21 01 02 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[New Residential Construction Limitation]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX 21 02 02 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Pre-Existing or Progressive Damage or Defect]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX 21 03 02 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Punitive Damages]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[CX 21 14 04 13]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - EIFS]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[CX 21 13 04 13]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Fungi Or Bacteria]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[CX 21 16 04 13]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Silica]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[CX 21 01 09 08]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Nuclear]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[CX 21 19 04 13]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Employment Related]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[CX 21 20 04 13]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Professional]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX 21 10 02 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Prior Completed or Abandoned Work]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX 21 11 02 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Drywall ]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX 21 13 02 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Cross Suits]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX 21 14 02 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Asbestos]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX 21 15 02 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Lead]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX 21 16 02 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Violation of Statutes]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX 21 17 02 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Wrap Up]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[HU 01 01 03 15]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Service of Suit]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[HU 01 02 03 15]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Hamilton Notice of Claims ]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[CX 21 30 10 15]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Cap on Losses From Certified Acts of Terrorism]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[Attach based on accept / reject Terrorism]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[EX N 005 06 16]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[Disclosure Pursuant to Terrorism Risk Insurance Act]]></title>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[Attach based on accept / reject Terrorism]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[CX 02 22 09 08]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[West Virginia Changes - Cancellation]]></title>
        <state><![CDATA[WV]]></state>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[WV Only]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
      </entry>
    </required>
    <optional>
      <entry>
        <name><![CDATA[CX 31 08 11 13]]></name>
        <category><![CDATA[Auto Liability]]></category>
        <lob><![CDATA[Auto Liability]]></lob>
        <title><![CDATA[WV Excess UM UIM]]></title>
        <state><![CDATA[WV]]></state>
        <state_exception><![CDATA[Attach in WV only based on UM acceptance and choice]]></state_exception>
        <required><![CDATA[O]]></required>
      </entry>
    </optional>
  </forms>
  <transaction_type><![CDATA[New Business]]></transaction_type>
  <ppt><![CDATA[1]]></ppt>
  <extra_heavy_trucks_medium><![CDATA[1]]></extra_heavy_trucks_medium>
  <al_combined_single_limit><![CDATA[1,000,000 CSL]]></al_combined_single_limit>
  <auto_year_established><![CDATA[2014]]></auto_year_established>
  <selected_excess_layer><![CDATA[1]]></selected_excess_layer>
  <gl_actual_premium><![CDATA[2,300]]></gl_actual_premium>
  <emp_liab_each_accident><![CDATA[$500,000]]></emp_liab_each_accident>
  <empl_liab_accid_effec_dt><![CDATA[07/22/2016]]></empl_liab_accid_effec_dt>
  <empl_liab_accid_expr_dt><![CDATA[07/22/2017]]></empl_liab_accid_expr_dt>
  <emp_liab_agg_policy_limit><![CDATA[$500,000]]></emp_liab_agg_policy_limit>
  <emp_liab_each_employee><![CDATA[$500,000]]></emp_liab_each_employee>
  <emp_benefit_liab><![CDATA[$500,000 Claims Made]]></emp_benefit_liab>
  <empl_bene_liab_effec_dt><![CDATA[07/18/2016]]></empl_bene_liab_effec_dt>
  <empl_bene_liab_expr_dt><![CDATA[07/18/2017]]></empl_bene_liab_expr_dt>
  <retro_date><![CDATA[1468454400]]></retro_date>
  <retro_date_string><![CDATA[2016-07-14T00:00:00+00:00]]></retro_date_string>
  <um_cov_question><![CDATA[1]]></um_cov_question>
  <um_cov_equal_question><![CDATA[1]]></um_cov_equal_question>
  <score_gl><![CDATA[67]]></score_gl>
  <uw_questions>
    <defense_cost><![CDATA[1]]></defense_cost>
    <rated_a><![CDATA[1]]></rated_a>
    <rated_b><![CDATA[1]]></rated_b>
    <claims5_yrs><![CDATA[None]]></claims5_yrs>
    <fleet_exceed25><![CDATA[0]]></fleet_exceed25>
    <sub_contract_work><![CDATA[1]]></sub_contract_work>
    <req_equal_limits><![CDATA[1]]></req_equal_limits>
    <perform_work><![CDATA[0]]></perform_work>
    <hazard_hauling><![CDATA[0]]></hazard_hauling>
  </uw_questions>
</result>
```

Comment: Do you need all children of entry (name. category, lob, title, state_exception,required) to match?

Comment: No I do not need all children of any entry to match.  just parents. Thanks for asking jdweng.

Comment: This might be easier to accomplish via XSLT rather than LINQ-to-XML.

Comment: don't think XSLT would work because I need to evaluate and do this for every xml file the code ever encounters at run-time.  Don't know how that could be done ahead of time in XSLT.  It you do Tim, please, show me how.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            GetNode((XElement)doc.FirstNode);
        }
        static void GetNode(XElement element)
        {
            // Loop through the XML nodes until the leaf is reached.
            // Add the nodes to the TreeView during the looping process.

            List<XElement> children = element.Elements().ToList();
            for (int index = children.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
            {
                XElement child = children[index];
                if (child.Name.LocalName == "entry")
                {
                    child.ReplaceWith(new XElement("entry_" + (index + 1).ToString(), child.Elements()));
                }
                GetNode(child);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Try code below to replace all tags.   Only thing that isn't exactly the same is the unnecessary CDATA is dropped.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            GetNode((XElement)doc.FirstNode);
        }
        static void GetNode(XElement element)
        {
            // Loop through the XML nodes until the leaf is reached.
            // Add the nodes to the TreeView during the looping process.

            List<XElement> children = element.Elements().ToList();
            var groups = element.Elements().GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName).ToList();
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                string tagName = group.Key;
                List<XElement> elements = group.ToList();
                for (int index = group.Count() - 1; index >= 0; index--)
                {
                    GetNode(elements[index]);
                    XElement newElement = new XElement(tagName + "_" + (index + 1).ToString(), new object[] { elements[index].Attributes(), elements[index].Elements()});
                    if (!newElement.HasElements) newElement.Add(elements[index].Value);
                    elements[index].ReplaceWith(newElement);


                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now if you only want the duplicates renumbered try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            GetNode((XElement)doc.FirstNode);
        }
        static void GetNode(XElement element)
        {
            // Loop through the XML nodes until the leaf is reached.
            // Add the nodes to the TreeView during the looping process.

            List<XElement> children = element.Elements().ToList();
            var groups = element.Elements().GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName).ToList();
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                string tagName = group.Key;
                List<XElement> elements = group.ToList();
                if (group.Count() == 1)
                {
                    GetNode(group.FirstOrDefault());
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int index = group.Count() - 1; index >= 0; index--)
                    {
                        GetNode(elements[index]);
                        XElement newElement = new XElement(tagName + "_" + (index + 1).ToString(), new object[] { elements[index].Attributes(), elements[index].Elements() });
                        if (!newElement.HasElements) newElement.Add(elements[index].Value);
                        elements[index].ReplaceWith(newElement);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code above jdweng.... it looks promising..  I will play with it, and see what I can do.  

One major issue however.  I didn't clearly state I won't know the structure of the xml file before I have to correct nodes that have the same ancestors/parents.  So I can't hard code the following with "forms", "required" and "entry".

var entries = doc.Descendants("forms").FirstOrDefault().Element("required").Elements("entry").ToList();

Thank you for your help.  I will keep trying to sort this out.

- John

Comment: same issue with this line:
entry.ReplaceWith(new XElement("entry_" + (++count).ToString(), entry.Elements()));

I will need to figure out how to append "_" + (++count).ToString() to whatever the node's name is, not hard coding "entry"  as I won't know the nodes I have to make unique ahead of runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the update jdweng.  I am getting somewhere with your code.  I will review your changes.  I have been thinking I should use a jagged array to keep track of the parents of any node that is at the same level and with the same name.  If nodes and level match, then compare all the parents.  That's my thought process anyways....

Comment: I updated code bu not working properly in VS 10.  Will try again at home with newer version.

Comment: Thanks for continuing trying to help me jdweng.  I am getting better at keeping track of the various node's parent names in a multidimensional array to compare against to try your code with a slight change.  Still working on it however.  - John

Comment: I got it working, but the unneeded CDATA gets dropped.

Comment: Thank you jdweng!! I really appreciate your help getting me over this issue.  Thank you. - John

Answer (score 0):

In VB this will create a copy of the XML and rename all entry nodes with an _number suffix that restart from 1 when the parent node changes.  The first part is just the data (XML) that you supplied.

```
    'to load from a file
    '  xe = XElement.Load("Your Path Here")

    ' for testing
    Dim xe As XElement
    xe = <result>
             <quote><![CDATA[1776.5]]></quote>
             <account_name><![CDATA[Acme Mountaineers]]></account_name>
             <account_number><![CDATA[CDTEST-07052016]]></account_number>
             <effective_dt><![CDATA[1467676800]]></effective_dt>
             <effective_dt_string><![CDATA[2016-07-05T00:00:00+00:00]]></effective_dt_string>
             <zip><![CDATA[25301]]></zip>
             <street><![CDATA[170 SE 3rd Ave]]></street>
             <city><![CDATA[CHARLESTON]]></city>
             <state><![CDATA[WV]]></state>
             <products>
                 <entry><![CDATA[gl]]></entry>
                 <entry><![CDATA[auto]]></entry>
             </products>
             <coverage_type><![CDATA[Occurrence]]></coverage_type>
             <product_type><![CDATA[Excess]]></product_type>
             <admitted_status><![CDATA[Non Admitted]]></admitted_status>
             <classifications>
                 <entry>
                     <location><![CDATA[1]]></location>
                     <street><![CDATA[170 SE 3rd Ave]]></street>
                     <city><![CDATA[CHARLESTON]]></city>
                     <county><![CDATA[KANAWHA]]></county>
                     <state><![CDATA[WV]]></state>
                     <territory><![CDATA[1]]></territory>
                     <zip><![CDATA[25301]]></zip>
                     <class_code><![CDATA[91582]]></class_code>
                     <class_code_desc><![CDATA[(91582) Contractors - subcontracted work - in connection with building construction, reconstruction,]]></class_code_desc>
                     <premium_basis><![CDATA[Total Cost]]></premium_basis>
                     <premium_basis_amount><![CDATA[200000]]></premium_basis_amount>
                     <authority><![CDATA[A]]></authority>
                 </entry>
             </classifications>
             <limit><![CDATA[1,000,000 CSL]]></limit>
             <limit_aggregate><![CDATA[1,000,000 CSL]]></limit_aggregate>
             <aggregate_prod_ops><![CDATA[1,000,000 CSL]]></aggregate_prod_ops>
             <exclude_prod_ops><![CDATA[0]]></exclude_prod_ops>
             <exclude_terrorism><![CDATA[1]]></exclude_terrorism>
             <forms>
                 <required>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX DS 01 05 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Declarations]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[HU DS 02 10 15]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Signature Endorsement]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX DS 02 05 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Schedule of Forms and Endorsements]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX DS 03 05 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Schedule of Controlling Underlying Insurance]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[CX 00 01 04 13]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Commercial Excess Liability Form]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX 21 01 02 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[New Residential Construction Limitation]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX 21 02 02 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Pre-Existing or Progressive Damage or Defect]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX 21 03 02 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Punitive Damages]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[CX 21 14 04 13]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - EIFS]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[CX 21 13 04 13]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Fungi Or Bacteria]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[CX 21 16 04 13]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Silica]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[CX 21 01 09 08]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Nuclear]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[CX 21 19 04 13]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Employment Related]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[CX 21 20 04 13]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Professional]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX 21 10 02 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Prior Completed or Abandoned Work]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX 21 11 02 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Drywall ]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX 21 13 02 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Cross Suits]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX 21 14 02 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Asbestos]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX 21 15 02 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Lead]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX 21 16 02 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Violation of Statutes]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX 21 17 02 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Exclusion - Wrap Up]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[HU 01 01 03 15]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Service of Suit]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[HU 01 02 03 15]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Hamilton Notice of Claims ]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[All Policies]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[CX 21 30 10 15]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Cap on Losses From Certified Acts of Terrorism]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[Attach based on accept / reject Terrorism]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[EX N 005 06 16]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[Disclosure Pursuant to Terrorism Risk Insurance Act]]></title>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[Attach based on accept / reject Terrorism]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[CX 02 22 09 08]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Common]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Common]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[West Virginia Changes - Cancellation]]></title>
                         <state><![CDATA[WV]]></state>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[WV Only]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[M]]></required>
                     </entry>
                 </required>
                 <optional>
                     <entry>
                         <name><![CDATA[CX 31 08 11 13]]></name>
                         <category><![CDATA[Auto Liability]]></category>
                         <lob><![CDATA[Auto Liability]]></lob>
                         <title><![CDATA[WV Excess UM UIM]]></title>
                         <state><![CDATA[WV]]></state>
                         <state_exception><![CDATA[Attach in WV only based on UM acceptance and choice]]></state_exception>
                         <required><![CDATA[O]]></required>
                     </entry>
                 </optional>
             </forms>
             <transaction_type><![CDATA[New Business]]></transaction_type>
             <ppt><![CDATA[1]]></ppt>
             <extra_heavy_trucks_medium><![CDATA[1]]></extra_heavy_trucks_medium>
             <al_combined_single_limit><![CDATA[1,000,000 CSL]]></al_combined_single_limit>
             <auto_year_established><![CDATA[2014]]></auto_year_established>
             <selected_excess_layer><![CDATA[1]]></selected_excess_layer>
             <gl_actual_premium><![CDATA[2,300]]></gl_actual_premium>
             <emp_liab_each_accident><![CDATA[$500,000]]></emp_liab_each_accident>
             <empl_liab_accid_effec_dt><![CDATA[07/22/2016]]></empl_liab_accid_effec_dt>
             <empl_liab_accid_expr_dt><![CDATA[07/22/2017]]></empl_liab_accid_expr_dt>
             <emp_liab_agg_policy_limit><![CDATA[$500,000]]></emp_liab_agg_policy_limit>
             <emp_liab_each_employee><![CDATA[$500,000]]></emp_liab_each_employee>
             <emp_benefit_liab><![CDATA[$500,000 Claims Made]]></emp_benefit_liab>
             <empl_bene_liab_effec_dt><![CDATA[07/18/2016]]></empl_bene_liab_effec_dt>
             <empl_bene_liab_expr_dt><![CDATA[07/18/2017]]></empl_bene_liab_expr_dt>
             <retro_date><![CDATA[1468454400]]></retro_date>
             <retro_date_string><![CDATA[2016-07-14T00:00:00+00:00]]></retro_date_string>
             <um_cov_question><![CDATA[1]]></um_cov_question>
             <um_cov_equal_question><![CDATA[1]]></um_cov_equal_question>
             <score_gl><![CDATA[67]]></score_gl>
             <uw_questions>
                 <defense_cost><![CDATA[1]]></defense_cost>
                 <rated_a><![CDATA[1]]></rated_a>
                 <rated_b><![CDATA[1]]></rated_b>
                 <claims5_yrs><![CDATA[None]]></claims5_yrs>
                 <fleet_exceed25><![CDATA[0]]></fleet_exceed25>
                 <sub_contract_work><![CDATA[1]]></sub_contract_work>
                 <req_equal_limits><![CDATA[1]]></req_equal_limits>
                 <perform_work><![CDATA[0]]></perform_work>
                 <hazard_hauling><![CDATA[0]]></hazard_hauling>
             </uw_questions>
         </result>
```

'============================================================

```
    Dim newXML As XElement = New XElement(xe) 'create a copy

    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = newXML...<entry>
    Dim lastParent As String = ""
    Dim ct As Integer

    For Each el As XElement In ie
        If el.Parent.Name.LocalName <> lastParent Then
            ct = 1
            lastParent = el.Parent.Name.LocalName
        Else
            ct += 1
        End If
        el.Name = "entry_" & ct.ToString
    Next

    newXML.Save("path here")
```

Comment: Thank you very much dbasnett for your help experience and time !  I am still going to review your code.  It could help me.  I am getting something figured out with jdweng's code and matching multiple parents via an array of identified same name/level nodes.